# Slow gesture sensitivity

Tags: xorg, multi-touch, gestures, touchegg

I have recently installed `X11 gestures` gnome shell extension that is running along with `touchegg` but the gesture sensitivity is too slow. It is becoming a pain to switch between the workspaces with 3 finger slide. When I do a 3 finger slide, most of the time it doesn't switch the workspace unless I do it too fast. Anyone who knows how to change the sensitivity for my gestures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. The file I needed to modify was `x11gestures@joseexposito.github.io/src/v40/SwipeTracker40.js`. In that file, the constant variable `const PERCENTAGE_MULTIPLIER` determines the sensitivity. I set that value to 12 and now it's a lot smoother

Answer (score 1):

Recently I got the same problem and saw your question and soltuion. It helped me to find another way how fix it. I just went to touchegg conf. file location(/usr/share/touchegg), opened it and find few properties there.
So i change *#value#*:  `<property name="action_execute_threshold">*#value#*</property>` to whatever feel's comfortable for me. And all gestures start working much better.
Hope this solution will help someone :)